# How to simplify procedure using IF statements inside where clause in PL/pgSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.5

I have quite a few procedures that rely on performing different queries based on the value of certain config variables. For example it'll be something like

```
IF (check_unit='Y') THEN
  SELECT my_key, my_id
  INTO l_my_key, l_my_id
  FROM data
  WHERE my_num = NEW.my_num AND
        my_data = NEW.my_date AND
        my_unit = NEW.my_unit;

ELSE
  SELECT my_key, my_id
  INTO l_my_key, l_my_id
  FROM data
  WHERE my_num = NEW.my_num AND
        my_data = NEW.my_date;
```

This is repeated over and over in multiple procedures across the database. I think there must be an easy way to do an IF or other condition so that if my_unit = 'Y' we will do the query with the 2 AND otherwise we will just do the 1 AND command without having to be so explicit writing both full queries out.

I'm still getting used to PL/pgSQL so if there is an easy way to do this I apologize. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated. If the way it is being done is the standard or accepted way then that's okay too.

Comment: 1) Postgresql 9.5 is ~1.5 years past EOL so if you are actually using it you should update. 2) See [Dynamic query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily move the `IF` condition into a [conditional expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) in the `WHERE` to choose your clauses:

```
SELECT my_key, my_id
INTO l_my_key, l_my_id
FROM data
WHERE (CASE WHEN check_unit = 'Y'
  THEN my_num = NEW.my_num AND
       my_data = NEW.my_date AND
       my_unit = NEW.my_unit
  ELSE my_num = NEW.my_num AND
       my_data = NEW.my_date
END);
```

Then simplify

```
SELECT my_key, my_id
INTO l_my_key, l_my_id
FROM data
WHERE my_num = NEW.my_num AND
      my_data = NEW.my_date AND
      (CASE WHEN check_unit = 'Y' THEN my_unit = NEW.my_unit ELSE TRUE END);
```

and further

```
SELECT my_key, my_id
INTO l_my_key, l_my_id
FROM data
WHERE my_num = NEW.my_num AND
      my_data = NEW.my_date AND
      (check_unit <> 'Y' OR my_unit = NEW.my_unit);
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL there is no *IF*, `where` is your logical work-horse. So something like:

```
select my_key, my_id
  into l_my_key, l_my_id
  from data
 where my_num = new.my_num 
   and my_data = new.my_date 
   and (   new.my_unit  <> 'Y' 
        or ( my_unit = new.my_unit and 
                new.my_unit  <> 'Y'
              ) 
          ) ;
```

However, please describe what you are actually trying to accomplish.

The above will only work within an insert or update row level trigger function. The pseudo row **`new` exists only in row triggers** and new.x will always be NULL on a delete trigger.  Further, triggers do not return values (other than a row image or null) and cannot be called directly.

Comment: There are multiple insert or update row level trigger functions with similar "duplicate" queries where the only thing changed is a single 'AND' if the condition is met so I was hoping for a way to either simplify the code or make it more efficient. Trigger is written in PL/pgSQL running postgres 9.5.5